# Cookie dough is too dry to shape, can I salvage the existing batch?

Tags: baking, cookies

I make this same Christmas cookie every year and this has never happened before. I made the dough on Wednesday, put in fridge, and today was baking them. I let them sit for maybe 20 min at room temperature and the ones I was able to twist, and keep dough together were dry after being baked.  The dough was falling apart when I was trying to make long ropes and then twist.

I put the rest of the dough back in the fridge since this morning. There is milk in the recipe. Should I add some milk to the hard dough or add the milk to dough  after sitting out at room temp when ready to twist?  I'm trying to salvage the rest of my dough.

I'm assuming it needs more liquid but I've *never* had to do this. Please help and let me know why this happened; why it seems dry and unable to stay together. I wrapped the dough in wax paper and put in a bag, maybe it wasn't sealed the best? Not sure.

Comment: Would you describe it as crumbling when you were trying to work it?  If so, see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10743/67

Comment: Perhaps the air is much drier and less humid due to the winter weather. This would change the amount of flour needed in the recipe to get the right consistency.

Answer (score 6):

This can happen, and it's not a big deal. I think adding a small amount of milk or water is the way to go. Let it come up to room temperature and then mix in milk a teaspoon at a time until you get the right consistency. It will probably take very little milk to make it right, so add it in small amounts!